# Merging Videos properly but that merged video is silent

Tags: objective-c

i am working on Merging videos,
    Here is my Code which is properly merging videos but that merged video is not audible(i am merging proper videos which is having sound but after merging that videos,that merged video is silent) can anyone help me with this :

```
NSValue *timeDur;
    NSMutableArray *arrInstructions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
    NSMutableArray *arrDuration = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;
    AVAsset *fAsset ;
    CMTime eachDuration = kCMTimeZero ;
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < self.arrVideoUrls.count; counter++) {
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    if (counter>0)
        fAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.arrVideoUrls[counter-1][@"VideoUrl"]]];
    AVAsset *firstAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.arrVideoUrls[counter][@"VideoUrl"]]];
    [track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:(counter == 0)?kCMTimeZero:eachDuration error:nil];
    eachDuration = CMTimeAdd(eachDuration, firstAsset.duration);
    timeDur = [NSValue valueWithCMTime:firstAsset.duration];
    [arrDuration addObject:timeDur];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:track];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
    CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 640.0/640.0;

    //CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
    if (counter == 0) {
        if(isFirstAssetPortrait_){
            FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE.width/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
            CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
            [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        }else{
            CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
            [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        }

    }else{
        if(isFirstAssetPortrait_){
            FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE.width/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
            CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
            [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
        }else{
            CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
            [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
        }
    }
    if (counter <self.arrVideoUrls.count - 1 ) {
        [FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:eachDuration];
    }

    [arrInstructions addObject:FirstlayerInstruction];
}
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
CMTime final;
for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < arrDuration.count; counter++) {
    NSValue *value = arrDuration[counter];
    CMTime timing  = kCMTimeZero ;
    [value getValue:&timing];
    if (counter == 0) {
        final = timing ;
    }else
        final = CMTimeAdd(final, timing);
}
MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,final);
MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [arrInstructions copy] ;
AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 10);
NSLog(@"%f",CMTimeGetSeconds(MainCompositionInst.frameDuration));
MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE.width, SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE.height);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080];
//AVAssetExportPreset960x540
exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
//exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
//exporter.audioMix = audioZeroMix ;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSLog(@"%@",exporter.error);
         Hide_Indicator ;
         [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
     });
 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live-editing audio is exactly like live-editing video. Go back to each movie and fetch the audio track and stick it into your mutable composition.

In this example, I grab the first five seconds of video and the last five seconds of video from a movie and put them one after the other in a new video:

```
 NSString* type = AVMediaTypeVideo;
 NSArray* arr = [oldAsset tracksWithMediaType:type];
 AVAssetTrack* track = [arr lastObject];
 CMTime duration = track.timeRange.duration;
 AVMutableComposition* comp = [AVMutableComposition composition];
 AVMutableCompositionTrack* comptrack = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:type preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
 [comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600) error:nil];
 [comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600) error:nil];
```

But the resulting video would be silent. So I also go back and fetch the corresponding audio:

```
type = AVMediaTypeAudio;
arr = [oldAsset tracksWithMediaType:type];
track = [arr lastObject];
comptrack = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:type   preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600) error:nil];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600) error:nil];
```